# How to describe an annoying teenager?

Tags: nouns

Sometimes a teenager may do some childish things. I want to know how to describe a teen with tendency of doing those. Is there an noun particularly be coined for this kind of teens? An daily conversation usage example is appreciated!

For childish things, I meant those things with the following condictions:

1. The starting point of doing so is that he/she just wanted to get attention from others, but doing it wrong. (So it in some rare condition it could be dangerous, but that's not my focus here...)
2. Since he/she doing it wrong, it is funny on the perspectives of other people, but they themselves didn't notice that.
3. It's not a bad thing, since he/she didn't hurt anyone, but I won't said it's a nice thing, since the motivation is to get attention. So it's just plain dump i think.

Comment: What kind of childish things? The word would highly depend on whether the behaviour is funny, destructive, naive, nice or just plain dumb.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will improve my description! @JohnHamilton

Comment: Sounds pretty much like a typical teenager to me. They do dumb things to get attention and to try to be cool. Do you have an example sentence that shows how you would like to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of a teenager who is acting childish:

If you want to be relatively polite:

> Stop acting so immature.
>
> Stop acting like a kid.
>
> You need to start acting your age.
>
> Don't be such a child.

Less polite:

> Grow up, would you?
>
> You're being a big baby.
>
> Take off your diapers and act like a grown-up.

There are, of course, many more rude expressions that would be even less polite, but I wouldn't recommend using them until you understand their proper context.

You can also use the synonyms of "immature":  *juvenile, puerile, adolescent, jejune, sophomoric, etc.*, albeit at the risk of sounding overly intellectual.  Again, proper context matters.